# Rails Devise login system. How to customize login flow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise

I have been using the devise gem for rails and I have facebook login system working. My problem is that there is so much going on in the background that I find it difficult to customize this. For example how do I change the path to the page the user is redirects to after the first time facevbook login, not the usual facebook login.

It adds this method to my user model

```
find_for_facebook_oauth
```

But what decides where it goes after that?

Also, If i make controller and extend the devise controllers will it call the code in the devise ones first? I dont get how that works.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Does this page from the devise wiki help you?
[How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: I want to differentiate between a user logging in and a user registering. Unfortunately, the login is in the user model so I can put redirects there.